# Обновление вопроса, которого не видно

Tags: дефект, поддержка, даты, обновление

Имеется вопрос: [Доступ из Python к Access](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/137156/176217), в инфоблоке справа написано, что он обновлен 18 октября 2015 года:

> [image: обновлён]

Однако никаких обновлений вопроса и ответов к нему по этой дате не видно. Во [временной шкале вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/137156/timeline) тоже пусто. Голосование не в счёт.

Это какое-то эхо миграции?

Comment: @NickVolynkin всё сломал :(

Comment: А Дух всегда явно поднимал?

Comment: @Qwertiy похоже, что только [год назад стал](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279201/339911). И ответ по обсуждаемой теме [получил плюс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/140406/timeline) через пару недель после даты обновления. Так что вероятно действительно дух шалит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На основании [предположения](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5190/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE#comment19233_5190) [@Qwertiy](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/178988/qwertiy) можно с 99% уверенностью сказать, что данное обновление отражает поднятие вопроса Духом.

[Явное упоминание](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279201/339911) о поднятии вопроса Духом было реализовано только лишь в начале мая 2016 года и случилось после упомянутой даты.

Также в поддержку этой версии говорит факт [получения голоса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/140406/timeline) ответом по обновлённому вопросу через пару недель после обновления. Известно, что Дух поднимает вопросы, ответы на которые имеют нулевой рейтинг и перестаёт это делать, когда рейтинг изменяется. После поднятия вопроса Духом шансы на голосование по ответу увеличиваются.